# while creating a route mechanism with raw nodejs, terminal says, "TypeError: requestedPath is not a function". No idea what and why is this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, object, routes

I was following along with a tutorial on youtube.
the dependencies are:

```
// depencies
const url = require("url")
const { notFound } = require("../pages/pageRoutes/notFoundHandler")
const router = require("../route")
```

against these, we, the tutor and me wrote these below

```
  let requestedPath = router[trimmedPath] ? trimmedPath : notFound;
  requestedPath(reqProperty, (statusCodes, payloads) => {
    statusCodes = typeof(statusCodes) === "number" ? statusCodes : 500;
    payloads = typeof(statusCodes) === "object" ? payloads : {};
    const payloadString = JSON.stringify(payloads);

    // final response
    res.writeHead(statusCodes);
    res.end(payloadString);
```

where `requestedPath` is a string variable that stores a valid path. but on the next line, that online tutor called(invoked) it saying that `requestedPath` is a function. as well as vs code terminal says `requestedPath` is not a function.

the`router` dependency looks like this

```
// dependencies
const {sampleHandle} = require('./pages/pageRoutes/sampleHandler');

const routes = {
    'sample': sampleHandle,
}
```

this is suppose to do the routing job as you can see.

I am new in node, so wanted to learn from the very basics.
now I need to know what's going on here that causes this error in mine but not on that internet teacher's machine.

the error on terminal

```
D:\WebDesigns\NodejsTestProject\components\handleReqRes.js:36
  requestedPath(reqProperty, (statusCodes, payloads) => {
  ^
TypeError: requestedPath is not a function
    at handler.modulerHandleReqRes (D:\WebDesigns\NodejsTestProject\components\handleReqRes.js:36:3)
```

Comment: If `requestedPath` is a string, what are you trying to do by calling it as a function?

Comment: thank you sir for your interest. basically, I did think that ` requestedPath `  was a string and that was a mistake. whereas it is a method defined 3 steps back.
I was able to fix the issue after a long while(since I'm not that excellent in syntax).